# SCORM - RTE reporting mechanism security

Tags: security, scorm, scorm2004

I am investigating SCORM compliance as an option for a software project I am involved in. If this is too esoteric for SO, I am sorry - not sure where else to turn.

I am a little confused as to how the SCO (Sharable Content Object) reports a quiz score, for example, to the LMS. From what I can gather from the official documentation, this is to be done using using `LMSSetValue` function in the RTE API object, which is just a bunch of Javascript.

This seems wildly insecure to me, as it takes nothing to rewrite the values passed to the LMS this way.

My question is therefore, am I missing something? Are SCOs meant simply to not report such values to the LMS? It is my impression it is the only permitted mode of communication between SCOs and the LMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript API is *the* way data is passed from the SCO to the LMS. Are there more secure ways to pass data? Sure. But the implementation is not brand-spanking new, remember. In addition, because of portability constraints, many of the most highly secure ways of passing data are not available to SCORM developers. Portability was the main priority of the standard, not security. There is a community of experts talking about what should replace SCORM. It's called [Project Tin Can](http://scorm.com/tincan/). And different ways of exchanging data, including cross-domain and server-side, are being discussed there.

Comment: You should also check out http://scorm.com/blog/2009/04/scorm-security-some-perspective/ to get some perspective on SCORM security. Yes, there are easy ways that somebody who knows JavaScript can manipulate the SCORM API, but there are much larger security holes inherent in online training.

Comment: Thank you for the links. My personal conclusion is that SCORM is not suitable for my project where security and confidentiality are priorities.

Comment: I agree with Mike (yet again!). You may want to look at AICC as an alterative to SCORM; it uses form posts to transmit data. Form posts over HTTPS is about as secure as any online transaction can realistically be. Is AICC perfect? Nope. But it can be more secure than SCORM when it comes to transmitting data.

Comment: Good idea to look at AICC. Or just do it from scratch, the way you want. Which, if you don't *need* to be able to say, for some reason, funding, stakeholders, whatever, that you adhere to x standard, might be the best way.